# Анимация чисел как в гугле (генератор случайных чисел) js

Tags: javascript, анимация

набираешь в гугле "генератор случайных чисел" и там появится ну собственно поля для ввода и генерации.
Подскажите пожалуйста как реализовать такую анимацию или откуда найти точно токую же (может как то можно извлекать код гугла ?)

Comment: вроде нет никакой анимации

Comment: вот скрин https://ibb.co/vsZWg4Y

Comment: формально это не анимация - это просто быстрая смена значений.

Comment: хорошо) а можете подсказать как это сделать или найти js код отвечающий за этот блок

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Формально тут нет анимации, просто быстрая смена значений.

Алгоритм может быть следующим

1. получить начальное число
2. получить конечное
3. определить несколько промежуточных чисел
4. сменять числа начиная с начального с небольшим интервалом.

```js
function random(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
}

function range(cur, next, count) {
  // ищем интервал между промежуточными значениями, если интервал слишком маленький устанавливаем 1
  var diff = Math.floor((next - cur) / count) || 1;

  // получаем промежуточные значения
  var res = [cur];
  for (var i = cur + diff; Math.abs(i - next) > Math.abs(diff); i += diff) {
    res.push(i);
  }
  res.push(next);

  return res;
}

var timer = null

function generate(min, max) {
  window.clearInterval(timer);
  var current = +out.value;
  var next = random(min, max);
  var rng = range(current, next, 25);
  timer = setInterval(() => {
    // на каждой итерации берем следующее значение, пока они не закончатся.
    out.value = rng.shift();
    if (!rng.length) window.clearInterval(timer);
  }, 10);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <output id="out">0</output>
  <div>
    <div>
      Min value: <input type="text" id="minimum" value="1" />
    </div>
    <div>
      Max value: <input type="text" id="maximum" value="1000000" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="button" value="Generate" onclick="generate(minimum.value, maximum.value)" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: если ввести в min-value и max-value одинаковые числа, начиная с 2, то генератор выводит: 0-1, хотя, по идее, должен выводить 2, не так ли?

Comment: @meine, может быть :-) я не делал никаких проверок, можно даже поменять местами мин и мах, или отрицательные повводить или вообще не числа :)

Comment: @meine, случайно число из интервала не правильно получаю :)

Comment: @Grundy Отлично спасибо) а подскажите еще как можно в эту скрипт поставить числа не рандомно а написать самому (масив чисел )

Comment: например numbers = [1, 47, 556, 687, 2132, 213234];

Comment: @Адрей, не совсем понял :-) куда именно вставить?

Comment: @Grundy в скрипте :-) в ручную написать чтобы нажали на кнопку с быстрой прокрутке была число 47 потом еще раз нажали 556 и так далиее (то есть число брались не рандомно а именно были написаны в ручную в скрипте )

Comment: @Адрей, собственно надо просто поменять строчку `var next = random(min, max);`, чтобы он брал следующее из массива

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110469/discussion-between-grundy-and-).